# RMySQL adding spaces to query making it fail

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to run a MySQL query using RMySQL which includes a `LIKE` and a custom variable inside the query.

Here is an example of my query

```
customvar= 'some text'
(simpleQuery<-paste("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NameOfField like '%",customvar,"%'")) 
res<-dbGetQuery(con, simpleQuery)
```

The thing is that for some reason simpleQuery interprets the query like this

```
[1] "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NameOfField '% some text %'"
```

Note the spaces before and after `some text` those are preventing my query to get proper results

I have no idea why those spaces are being generated. I tested my query without those spaces and it does give back results, so I am sure that those spaces are making my query fail.

Any idea of a way around this issue?

Versions:
R 2.14.0 / RMySQL 0.8

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default in `paste` is `sep=' '` (space), but you probably intended `sep=''` (empty string). In recent R you can use `paste0` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it looks like paste0 is only available on a dev version of R as I am getting "could not find function "paste0"" with R 2.14, I will try to install a dev version and check if that solves the issue. Thanks again for the quick help!

Comment: my bad! it looks like current R version is 2.14.1! I will check it out now

Comment: For anyone else reading this post, it looks like paste0 is not available on R 2.14.1 either, but I noticed that `sep` is an argument you can use with `paste` just like this `sep=""`

Comment: `paste0` has also been available in the gsubfn package for many years.

Answer (score 0):

You get gsubfn and solve this problem by doing this at the command line (not in R):

```
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gsubfn/gsubfn_0.5-7.tar.gz
rm gsubfn_0.6-3.tar.gz
```

This installs a version of gsubfn that is compatible with 2.14